# Merged DLL with ILMerge is working under clr4 but under clr2

Tags: ilmerge

I am running ILMerge with the following parameters:

```
Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe'
     [exec] '/keyfile:C:\myKey.snk'
     [exec] '/target:library'
     [exec] '/targetplatform:v2,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727'
     [exec] '/copyattrs'
     [exec] '/lib:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727'
     [exec] '/log:log.txt'
     [exec] '/out:C:\mergedDll.dll'
     [exec] 'mydll1.dll'
     [exec] 'mydll2.dll'
```

The reproduced dll appears to work with CLR4 but not with CLR2. When I am testing the dll with Corflags, I get the following output:

```
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 9
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 1
```

The error I get with CLR2 is:

```
error BC30009: Reference required to assembly 'mergedDll, Version=1.2.3.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234dbf1234567b' containing the implemented interface 'com.mycompany.myapplication.MyInterface'. Add one to your project.
```

The interface mentioned above is written in J#.
How can I make the merged dll work under CLR2?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the original DLL's CLR2 or CLR4?

Comment: All the merged DLLs are from CLR2:
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0

Comment: I meant that both the merged dll and original dlls are CLR2

Comment: Are you using ILMerge from CLR2 or CLR4?

Comment: I downloaded ILMerge from research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx, as far as I know it is a separate unit which is not clr2 or clr4 based.

Comment: Potentially you could [embed the dlls as resources and load them on demand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) instead.  Microsoft recommends this technique when WPF assemblies are involved (they don't work with ILMERGE for some reason).

Comment: Thanks! I am less keen on using the embed option as I fear it will raise performance or maintainability issues